How to work with routing without changing the url in SolidJS
I am new to SolidJS and I am working on a project where I don't have to change the URL while changing the route.
For example, I would like to navigate to a different page without typing the path manually.

What do you mean by changing route without changing url? That is not possible because they are tightly coupled, one listen to the other. Do you mean hash routing, routes with #?

I mean for example going for a component to another by clicking on a button without changing the url. Is there any other way in case the routing is not possible?

Solid router already behaves like that. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78245608/7134134 If you are not using ssr, make sure to use hash router.

Solid router already behaves like that. It does not matter if you navigate to the target URL via link or by manually typing the path, the router will load the related component.
If you are not going to use SSR, make sure to use HashRouter instead of Router, otherwise you will have page not found error on page refresh because you will landing on a different page. Another solution would be returning the same SPA from the server, in that case, client side application will be loaded on a different page.
Here is a simple application:
import { A, Route, Router, HashRouter } from '@solidjs/router';
import { Component, JSX } from 'solid-js';
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';

const Layout: Component<{ children: JSX.Element }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><A href='/'>Home</A></li>
        <li><A href='/blog'>Blog</A></li>
        <li><A href='/users'>Users</A></li>
      </ul>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

const Home: Component<{}> = () => <Layout>This is Home page!</Layout>
const Users: Component<{}> = () => <Layout>This is Users page!</Layout>
const Blog: Component<{}> = () => <Layout>This is Blog page!</Layout>
const NotFound: Component<{}> = () => <Layout>Not Found!</Layout>

function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
      <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
      <Route path="*404" component={NotFound} />
    </HashRouter>
  );
}

render(() => <App />, document.body);

Layout in not strictly necessary but the A component requires you to keep it under a Route component. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78245608/7134134
If you don't want to use URL at all, neither let the user change the URL path, then you don't need a router, just use a Switch component. But you will be giving up any benefits that are brought by using a router, such as bookmarking, providing visual feedback to the user via URL etc.

I don't want to change the url. It must stay the same. I used Switch but with I have sub-submenus and it started to be complexed to handle.

We use a router to manage complexity and there is no out of the box solution for what you are asking. Maybe you can use the Dynamic component along with Show or Switch but since you are new to Solid, it will take time.
